# Connecting Three Tables SQL

Tags: sql

Hello what I'm trying to do is retrieve values from tables but I'm having a problem with forming a correct SQL statement. This is what i have.

```
 $qry_display = "SELECT a.section_id, b.section_id,b.student_id,c.* 
                   FROM tbl_section AS a 
                   LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_er AS b On a.section_id = b.section_id
                   LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_enroll AS c On b.student_id = c.student_id
                  WHERE b.student_id=c.student_id
                    AND a.bname='$branch'";
```

This is my database structure.

tbl_section:

```
section_id    section_name    sy    adviser_id    level
```

tbl_er:

```
student_id    section_id
```

tbl_enroll

```
student_id    fname    lname
```

I'm having problems with forming the proper sql statement would appreciate any help on how to do it right. What i want is to show all students Under a given section.

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by a "correct SQL statement"?

Comment: what do you want to retrieve?

Comment: @JackManey correct statement to get the values i desire. So far I'm having a bit of a problem to do that. John Students under a given section.

Comment: Firstly, if you're using PHP, the last line should be a.bname='" . $branch . "'". Secondly, you're doubling up your last join with the first where condition.

Comment: also, table a doesn't appear to have a column "bname"

Comment: And the values that you desire are.....? **We aren't mind readers.**

Comment: @JackManey tbl_enroll values that are under the section in tbl_section

Comment: Okay, so why doesn't your query above give you what you want?

Comment: I think I'm using incorrect parameters. It is just spatting out tbl_enroll values that are not under a specific section

Comment: Wich RDBMS are you using, MS SQL Server I guess, or another one, please retag your question. Also add some data to test and whole schema as requested, it helps to get the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In what table `bname` belongs? change `bname` into `sectionname`. Try this one,

```
SELECT  c.*
FROM    tbl_section a
        INNER JOIN tbl_er b
            on a.section_ID = b.section_ID
        INNER JOIN tbl_enroll c
            ON b.student_ID = c.student_ID
WHERE   a.sectionname = 'sectionNameHere'
```

Comment: Trying this out bname is on tbl_section forgot to put it out. Trying to understand this

Comment: @Tony if you try to execute the query i gave you, what's the result?

Comment: @Tony can you post the whole schema and sample records on your database?